# Can't get php to run on Amazon Lightsail

Tags: php, html, forms, apache2

I'm trying to run a very file file upload thing on an amazon lightsail machine running apache that I own. For some reason when I click submit the next page displays the html but I get an error saying method wasn't post and to use enctype. I added this to my form page and nothing changed unfortunately.

**index.html**

```
<form action="submission.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="pdf">Upload your pdf</label>
<input type="file" id="pdf" name="pdf" accept=".pdf"></br></br>
<label for="pics"> Optional extra credit </label>
<input type="file" id="pics" name="pics" accept="image/*"></br></br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I then use something like `$_POST["pdf"]` to retrieve the information

please help

EDIT: while writing this post my lightsail instance stopped working so i can't get the exact code

Comment: Nothing to do with lightsail. You'd have the same problem if you ran it on your local machine. Read the manual on file uploads: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP handles form-uploaded files in the [$_FILES](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) superglobal variable, not in the `$_POST`.

You'll be able to access them in `$_FILES['pdf']` and `$_FILES['pics']`